# Combine two images with CGAffineTransform

Tags: swift, ios11, swift4, apple-vision

I am using the new Apple Vision API's VNImageTranslationAlignmentObservation to get a CGAffineTransform returned. The idea is that you pass it two images that can be merged together and it returns the CGAffineTransform so that you can do so. I have managed to get the code working so that i get a CGAffineTransform returned but after a lot of reading im at a loss as how i can merge two images with the information.

My code is here:

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ImageTranslation {

    let referenceImage: CGImage!
    let floatingImage: CGImage!
    let imageTranslationRequest: VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest!

    init(referenceImage: CGImage, floatingImage: CGImage) {
        self.referenceImage = referenceImage
        self.floatingImage = floatingImage
        self.imageTranslationRequest = VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCGImage: floatingImage, completionHandler: nil)
    }


    func handleImageTranslationRequest() -> UIImage {
        var alignmentTransform: CGAffineTransform!
        let vnImage = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
        try? vnImage.perform([imageTranslationRequest], on: referenceImage)
        if let results = imageTranslationRequest.results as? [VNImageTranslationAlignmentObservation] {
            print("Image Transformations found \(results.count)")
            results.forEach { result in
                alignmentTransform = result.alignmentTransform

                print(alignmentTransform)
            }
        }

        return applyTransformation(alignmentTransform)

    }

    private func applyTransformation(_ transform: CGAffineTransform) -> UIImage {
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: referenceImage)
        return image
    }
}
```

The printed transform i get is like so `CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: 672.0, ty: 894.0)`

How can i apply this two the two images passed in?

Comment: I think it caused by you do nothing in applytransformation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with some examples (portrait images only but should work with landscape also) and this has worked:

```
func mergeImages(first image1:UIImage, second image2:UIImage, transformation: CGAffineTransform) -> UIImage {

    let size = CGSize(width: image1.size.width + image2.size.width - (image2.size.width - transformation.tx), height: image1.size.height + image2.size.height - (image2.size.height - transformation.ty))

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)

    return renderer.image { context in
        let pointImg2 = CGPoint.zero.applying(transformation)
        image2.draw(at: pointImg2)

        let pointImg1 = CGPoint.zero
        image1.draw(at: pointImg1)
    }
}
```

Let me know if it isn't working (upload your sample images if you can) and I'll fix it.